# Extjs: How to bind the tree with a data grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tree, which is like:

```
A
|-B1
  |-C1
  |-C2
|-B2
```

I want a data grid to change the data when I click on all the nodes, like, when I click on A:

```
B1...detail
B2...detail
```

When I click on B1:

```
C1...detail
C2...detail
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Any version of ExtJS in particular or ExtJS 5.1 will do?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes  am sorry but I didn't find the method in the docs, do I need to bind a method or something?

Comment: Binding is just helps you getting things done quicker... It is not necessary, but only works with ExtJS 5+

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I am still not sure how to do this, Listen to events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tree panel and a grid panel.

Listen to the itemclick event, then reload or filter the grid.